# Get deauthenticating local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) when script is run by my service but not when launch it myself

Tags: networking

As the title of my post say it, I have a script (below) running into a service that is in charged to bring on the wireless connection (WPA2) and if it can not, it bring on Access Point mode.

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Connected"
else
        echo "Try to get a connection"
        pkill wpa_supplicant
        systemctl stop dnsmasq
        systemctl stop hostapd
        #systemctl disable dnsmasq
        systemctl disable hostapd
        ifdown wlan0
        ifup wlan0=wlan_user


        wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                echo "Connected"
        else
                        echo "Access point mode"
                        ifdown wlan0
                        systemctl restart dnsmasq
                        systemctl restart hostapd

                        ifconfig wlan0 up
                        ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.1/24

                        #iptables -t nat -F
                        #iptables -F
                        #iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
                        #iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
                        #echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        fi
fi

cp /etc/network/interfaces /tmp/interfaces
```

To test if it works, I launch it in terminal and it works great but when it is launched by my service, it connects but disconnects immediately with "Get deauthenticating  local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)". 
Note : It works when connecting to a non WPA wireless connection